# jswing running a long task

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, swingworker

I am new to java

I have a function **runner** inside **PhotoPoster class** (PhotoPoster class is a Jframe with lots of buttons and other GUI elements)

it contains a **START** button when I **click** on **START** it executes the **runner function** which runs an activity & thats takes a very long time 
and   other GUI components are not accessible unless the runner functions completes.

I want this to work in separate thread or any other solution to help me

what I currently do is

I have made a another class **GuiWorker.java**

```
public class GuiWorker extends SwingWorker<Integer, Integer>{

    public GuiWorker() throws IOException {

    }

    protected Integer doInBackground() throws Exception {
        PhotoPoster photoPoster = new PhotoPoster();
        photoPoster.ruuner();
        return 0;
    }

    protected void done() {
        System.out.println("done");
    }
}
```

PhotoPoster.java

on button click

```
    private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         


       // PhotoPoster photoPoster = new PhotoPoster();


              //ruuner();


   EventQueue.invokeLater( new Runnable() {



       @Override
      public void run() {

          try {
              new GuiWorker().execute();
          } catch (IOException ex) {
              Logger.getLogger(PhotoPoster.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
          }

          }
        });




    }
```

it gives system out **done** but not performing **runner** function  activity

**Please Help me to sort out this error or any other solution**

Comment: It looks like the cause is in PhotoPoster class.

Comment: Can you paste it here please

Comment: You're trying to run uncompilable code -- don't do this! Fix the compilation error first before ever trying to run the code. The compiler error message will tell you exactly where the error is, and usually will lead you to a solution.

Comment: If you still need help, post for us the **compiler's** error message, and indicate which lines are causing it (the message will tell you this).

Comment: i have made changes in code now its not giving the error but not performing the runner function

Comment: I see no way to guess what's wrong based on what you've posted so far. Consider creating and posting an [sscce](http://sscce.org) or a [minimal example program/mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) where you condense your code into the smallest bit that still compiles and runs, has no outside dependencies (such as need to link to a database or images), has no extra code that's not relevant to your problem, but still demonstrates your problem.

Answer (score 1):

It looks as though you are queuing your long running thread back onto the Event Dispatch Thread, which means that even though you are doing `invokeLater` it will still block the thread.

You need to use a [SwingWorker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html).